# Twitter Bootstrap: Where can I find the subnav nav-pills from the Documentation?

Tags: navigation, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html
and I'm looking for the grey/blue navbar just under the heading.

It's nowhere in the Documentation and I just can't find anything through Google. It's just what I need though for my main navigation.

I hope someone can help me, I'm starting to get crazy because I can't find anything about this.

Comment: That subnav is not part of the bootstrap framework "yet", it is scheduled to be on some future releases i believe, though you can strip it from the documentation if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've looking for a scroll spy http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

For styling you should look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#variables
Scroll down ad you will see **Components/Navbar**

Comment: right ... I'm not looking for the functionality though, just for the styling and the look.

Comment: Well no not really, I already saw that section and I know that I can edit it all myself. I just need the exact properties for this navbar on their site, which I cannot find anywhere.

Comment: @Mexxer all I can suggest you Is something like: `@navbarBackground: @grayLighter` `@navbarBackgroundHighlight: @white` `@navbarText: @linkColor` `@navbarLinkColor: @linkColor` `@navbarLinkColorHover: @linkColorHover` `@navbarLinkColorActive: `@gray` `@navbarLinkBackgroundHover: @grayLighter` `@navbarLinkBackgroundActive: @grayLight` and you can play with it

Answer (score 0):

@Mexxer check this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css
You can find .subnav class.  Section /* Subnav */. Regards

Comment: Not really! There is no subnav class over there.